# How to deserialize to arraylist with annotations

Tags: android, jackson

I need deserialize a string(json) to a arraylist inside a model. I'm using the Jackson-Annotation library to do this. Anyone can help me?

I've tried this, but doesn't work:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = Model.class)
private ArrayList<Model> model;
```

or:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = ArrayModel.class) //ArrayModel extends arrayList<Model>
private ArrayList<Model> model;
```

Sample:

```
public class Model extends BaseModel {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private int id;

  @JsonDeserialize(as = ModelTwo.class)
  private ArrayList<ModelTwo> modelTwo;

  public ArrayList<ModelTwo> getModelTwo() {
    return modelTwo;
  }

  public void setModelTwo(ArrayList<ModelTwo> modelTwo) {
    this.modelTwo = modelTwo;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this!

You need say the type of Object and the type of content.
After this, you need create a new Json with properties on params.

On first model:

```
@JsonProperty("property")
@JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=ModelTwo.class)
  private List<ModelTwo> modelsTwo;
```

On second model:

```
@JsonCreator
  public ModelTwo(
      @JsonProperty("id") int id,
      @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
```